# Converting Array stored as a String to a List object in JavaString

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list

I have the following list:

```
nested_list = [
  ["[63]"],
  ["[61]"],
  ["[7]"],
  ["[63]"],
  ["[80, 18]"],
  ["[80, 43, 18, 20]"]
]
```

Which is a mess I know, but this is the data that I have to deal with at the moment and
I need it to be like this:

```
[63, 61, 7, 63, 80, 18, 80, 43, 18, 20]
```

So basically converting it into a list of numbers. Is this doable using as minimum loops as possible?

I have used flat() `nested_list .flat(2)` and ended up with the following result:

```
[ '[63]', '[61]', '[7]', '[63]', '[80, 18]', '[80, 43, 18, 20]' ]
```

Also tried reduce + concat following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) but since it is a string, it is not working and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.flatMap()` + `JSON.parse()` can do this quite easily

```js
const nested_list = [
  ["[63]"],
  ["[61]"],
  ["[7]"],
  ["[63]"],
  ["[80, 18]"],
  ["[80, 43, 18, 20]"]
];

const result = nested_list.flatMap(JSON.parse);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is amazing!
Learning tons here :)